# uitableview contentInset issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have strange issue with `contentInsent`. I am implementing "Pull & release" to refresh on UITableView and everything works fine, but in some cases I would like to display "loading" status without user interaction. So I thought I will simply use `contentInset` in the following way:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Everything works fine for 1 or 2 cells displayed - out of 3 possible on the view. However once the number of cells grows my banner at the top does not get displayed, at the same time manually scrolling works fine. Do I have to move the scroll besides moving content?

Answer (score 32):

OK, so I found the answer by playing a bit with different values. Turnes out that in the case described above besides setting `contentInset` you have to also setup `contentOffset`. In my case the following code worked:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, -60.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems to be working. Also, feel free to accept your own answer if it provides working solution

Comment: Interesting note for future readers. UICollectionView handles this automatically. UITableVIew does not. Can be very confusing if you switch between the two expecting equal APIs

Answer (score 2):

this gives better results:

```
CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offset);
```